# How to extract title from uploaded user file Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am building a django web application where user upload a file  (.docx), But before saving it I want a function that open the file that is being uploaded on runtime, Grab the title of that file and save that in title field in model.
my models.py file is:

```html
class FileUpload(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True , null=True)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='files')




    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('home')
```

Remember that I want to do this when user upload the file but that file save with the title inside of that .docx

Comment: To do this I would suggest reading how to open .docx files in python, how to read the file and then save that information in a variable. Unfortunately this has nothing to do with django per se. A quick search lead me to this: https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter13/ Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

From [the official django website](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/file-uploads/):

You can use something akin to this:

in **forms.py**

```py
from django import forms

class UploadFileForm(forms.Form):
    file = forms.FileField()
```

in **views.py**

```py
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import UploadFileForm
from .models import FileUpload

def upload_file(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            # the file is valid, we handle it
            f_u = FileUpload()
            f_u.file = request.FILES["file"]
            f_u.title = f_u.file.name
            f_u.author = request.user() # please ensure that you are logged in
            f_u.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/success/url/')
    else:
        form = UploadFileForm()
    return render(request, 'upload.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: I appreciate you but this is not what I want . I want a function that open the file that is being uploaded, grab its title . and put that title into title of the model

Comment: Ahhh, ok. That entirely depends on the way the file is written then. I recommend searching for python-docx, then, but I've never used it. Write a function with it, and call it in the `the file is valid, we handle it` section